# KMean and PCA connection

Tags: java, python, c++, opencv, pca

As I understand pattern recognition, PCA is used to remove unnecessary data in the dataset so that when the dataset will be used in a KMean, it will perform less than a dataset not being PCA'd. So, I can have code(pseudocode) something like this:

```
 assign .csv to var DATA
 PCA_DATA = PCAcompute(DATA)
 result = Kmean(PCA_DATA)
 plotToGraph(result)
```

Am I correct?

I've been looking for sample programs where it imports a csv then do some clustering with PCA for almost a MONTH now. What I need to do is to compare the output of a Kmean result to a Kmean result with PCA using the iris dataset.

Comment: In Python, with the right libraries, it's `X = numpy.asarray(pandas.read_csv(path)); X = sklearn.decomposition.PCA(n_components=n).fit_transform(X); cl = sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=k).fit_predict(X)` (where the "right" libs are just my favorites).

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to understand your statements.

For starters, PCA is Principal Component Analysis. This is a process that takes high-dimensional data and tries to find a lower-dimensional (hyper)plane in which that data (almost) lies. So, it removes unnecessary dimensions.

With `KMean` you probably mean `k-means clustering`. That works *much* faster in lower-dimensional spaces, so PCA is a viable way to reduce the number of dimensions.

(Program requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow)

Comment: It's not so much about speed. K-means suffers from the "curse of dimensionality", meaning that in very high-dimensional spaces, the notion of Euclidean distance breaks down and all points are roughly equidistant. PCA dampens that effect while retaining the "interesting" dimensions.

Comment: @larsmans: high-dimensional isn't an exact term. I'm not sure whether k-means works in a reasonable time if you have sufficient dimensions to suffer from the curse. Probably depends on the number of points you have.

Comment: My data typically has 1000s of dimensions at the very least, does that count as high-dimensional?

Comment: Oh, certainly, at that point I don't think k-means is going to work at all. But I have to wonder whether reducing it to a "mere" 100 dimensions is low enough for k-means clustering to work.

Comment: I assure you it works pretty well :) The other day I reduced 3e6 dimensions to 10k and got a few hundred quite informative clusters.

Answer (score 0):

I did not use KMean but I used PCA for my neural network training data to reduce features. It is in C++ interface of OpenCV. Let's start by reading csv file. My csv file is like :

```
im_path_1;label1  
im_path_2;label2
```

So to read that csv file, my function :

```
void read_csv(const string& filename, vector& images, vector& labels, char separator = ';') 
{
    std::ifstream file(filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);
    if (!file) 
    {
        string error_message = "No valid input file was given, please check the given filename.";
        CV_Error(1, error_message);
    }
    string line, path, classlabel;
    while (getline(file, line)) 
    {
        stringstream liness(line);

        getline(liness, path, separator);
        getline(liness, classlabel);

        if(!path.empty() && !classlabel.empty()) 
        {
            Mat im = imread(path, 0);

            images.push_back(im);
            labels.push_back(atoi(classlabel.c_str()));
        }
    }
}
```

It is holding data in vector of Mat variables. OpenCV's PCA requires data to be rolled as row vectors in a Mat variable. To do that :

```
Mat rollVectortoMat(const vector<Mat> &data)
{
   Mat dst(static_cast<int>(data.size()), data[0].rows*data[0].cols, CV_32FC1);
   for(unsigned int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
   {
      Mat image_row = data[i].clone().reshape(1,1);
      Mat row_i = dst.row(i);                                       
      image_row.convertTo(row_i,CV_32FC1, 1/255.);
   }
   return dst;
}
```

A simple usage of this functions :

```
int main()
{

    PCA pca;

    vector<Mat> images_train;
    vector<int> labels_train;

    read_csv("train1k.txt",images_train,labels_train);

    Mat rawTrainData = rollVectortoMat(images_train);   

    int pca_size = 500;

    Mat trainData(rawTrainData.rows, pca_size,rawTrainData.type());
    Mat testData(rawTestData.rows,pca_size,rawTestData.type());


    pca(rawTrainData,Mat(),CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW,pca_size);

    for(int i = 0; i < rawTrainData.rows ; i++)
        pca.project(rawTrainData.row(i),trainData.row(i));

    cout<<trainData.size()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`trainData` variable is the reduced version of the train set. And for `pca_size` variable; instead of using it as `500`; you can give pca to `0.95` to retain `%95` variance. I hope this helps for the PCA part. I used this reduced data to train a Neural Network.